# Maven - can't access nested class inside of artifact dependency

Tags: java, maven, groovy, pom.xml, multi-module

I recently started converting a large Ant project over to a Maven multi-module project when I ran across an interesting error. The problem I keep having is that I am not able to access my nested classes from another artifact even though they are in the same package (com.mypackage for example).

For this project, we were storing our SQL queries in Groovy classes (multiline strings are awesome) and referencing them in our compiled Java code. Something like this:

ShipmentPackingQueries.groovy - all groovy files are under src/main/groovy

```
    package com.mypackage;

    class ShipmentPackingQueries {
        static class Queries {
            public static class Cartons {
                @Language("MySQL")
                static final String query1 = ''' query '''
            }

            static class CartonItems {
                @Language("MySQL")
                static final String query2 = ''' query '''
            }

            // and so on....
        }
    }
```

This file gets compiled into a jar that is used later: mylibrary-core.jar. These are my maven-compiler-plugin settings - the JDK version is auto-detected in a  tag and is openjdk 1.8 on my machine:

```
    <!-- defined in the parent pom that all modules in the project inherit from -->
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <!-- 2.8.0-01 and later require maven-compiler-plugin 3.1 or higher -->
                        <version>3.5.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                                <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                                <version>2.9.1-01</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <!-- for 2.8.0-01 and later you must have an explicit dependency on groovy-eclipse-batch -->
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                                <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                                <version>2.3.7-01</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <!-- Set explicitly in the pom files for mylibrary-core and rest-core -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

When I watch the compile time output for the artifact mylibrary-core, I can see that the classes are being created successfully.

```
    [writing    com/mypackage/ShipmentPackingQueries$Queries$Shipments.class - #856]
    [writing    com/mypackage/ShipmentPackingQueries$Queries$CartonTypes.class - #857]
    [writing    com/mypackage/ShipmentPackingQueries$Queries$CartonItems.class - #858]
    [writing    com/mypackage/ShipmentPackingQueries$Queries$Cartons.class - #859]
    [writing    com/mypackage/ShipmentPackingQueries$Queries.class - #860]
    [writing    com/mypackage/ShipmentPackingQueries$Queries$Feed.class - #861]
```

I confirmed that these class files make into the artifact jar file as well. The problem is when I try to use the queries from another artifact: rest-core. I have set up rest-core to depend on the artifact mylibrary-core. Here's a sample file from rest-core:

ShipmentPackingResource.java - all java files are under src/main/java

```
    package com.mypackage;
    import static com.mypackage.ShipmentPackingQueries.Queries;

    public class ShipmentPackingResource {
        public void get() {
            Database.executeQuery(Queries.Cartons.getQuery1());
        }
    }
```

The artifact rest-core fails to compile with a message "Cartons cannot be resolved or is not a field". I only see two occurrences of ShipmentPackingQueries being loaded when looking at the output:

```
    [reading    com/mypackage/ShipmentPackingQueries.class]
    [reading    com/mypackage/ShipmentPackingQueries$Queries.class]
```

Any ideas as to why maven-compiler-plugin isn't reading in the other class files that go with ShipmentPackingQueries? I know I can make it work if I move the classes from rest-core into mylibrary-core, but I would like to keep the code in my modules as specific as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Try making the class that you're getting error for `public` that way you'll be able to rule out the scope error,

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I made it so that `ShipmentPackingQueries` is `public` and `Queries` and `Cartons` are marked `public static`. The error persists: "Cartons cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: That leads me to believe that they're not on the classpath, can you verify if the other Jar `mylibrary-core.jar` is on classpath.

Comment: Oddly enough, I can see `mylibrary-core.jar` listed on the classpath when compiling rest-core. It has all of the nested classes for `ShipmentPackingQueries` as well. The line above it says "Using Groovy-Eclipse compiler to compile both Java and Groovy files", but I wouldn't think that should matter.